# Genymotion Unfortunately gallery has stopped

Tags: android, react-native, genymotion

I use genymotion to develop apps. 
My virtual device is Google Nexus 5X - 6.0.0 1080x1920, but when i click to open directly gallery from virtual device, the device has error: Unfortunately gallery has stopped.

[image]

I can't fix this error.
My app that i deverloped need access to gallery, and now i can't debug it.

Comment: What error log are you getting?

Comment: @Piyush what the way can i see the logs of Genymotion?

Comment: please post logcat also

Comment: No, i only open gallery on Genymotion virtual device, dont open from my app!

Comment: how to develop apps using Genymotion??? thats really complicated what you mean is you are using Genymotion to test your app. I dont know the reason but my suggestion is you use Android Studio Emulator. fast and easy.

Answer (score 0):

As you are running your app on **Android 6.0 (Marshmallow)** you should make **permission check to read or write gallery** otherwise app will crash.

Permission check should looks like this :

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback{

private static final int REQUEST_WRITE_PERMISSION = 123;

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
 if (requestCode == REQUEST_WRITE_PERMISSION && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {            
    openGallery();
}
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
requestPermission();
}

private void requestPermission() {
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_WRITE_PERMISSION);
} else {
    openGallery();
  }
}
}
```

And don't forget to add permission in `Manifest.xml` :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```